# Microsoft dynamics nav 2009, how to show line numbers in object designer?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am using Microsoft dynamics nav 2009, but in object designer I dont see the line numbers. IT is very handy for debugging if you can see the line numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible - sorry. 
This is one of the new features (sic!) of the new C/AL Designer in NAV2016

Cheers!